# Android - How to update Status on Facebook attaching a picture

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, attachment

I'm using the Facebook's SDK for Android. I'm using the newStatusUpdateRequest() method to update my Status with a simple message, it works fine. But I don't find the way to attach a picture or an URL to the post.

```
private void postStatusUpdate() {
        if (canPresentShareDialog) {
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilderForLink().build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        } else if (user != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
            final String message = getString(R.string.status_update, user.getFirstName(), (new Date().toString()));
            Request request = Request
                    .newStatusUpdateRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), message, place, tags, new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            showPublishResult(message, response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
        }
    }
```

I was reading also this link, with all the facebook API methods, but I can't find the way to post both in my Status: a message and a picture:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/Request/#newStatusUpdateRequest

Has anyone solved already a similar problem?

Update. I think to post a picture I should use the method:

```
public static Request newGraphPathRequest(Session session, String graphPath, Callback callback)
```

Where graphPath should be the link to the picture. But I don't know how to join both, message and picture in the same Request.

Thanks you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it:

```
private void postStatusUpdate() {
        if (canPresentShareDialog) {
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilderForLink().build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        } else if (user != null && hasPublishPermission()) {

            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);

            Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), image, new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    showPublishResult(getString(R.string.photo_post), response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                }
            });
            final String message = getString(R.string.status_update, user.getFirstName(), (new Date().toString()));

            Bundle params = request.getParameters();
            params.putString("message", message);

            request.executeAsync();

        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
        }
    }
```

If anyone has got a better solution, feel free to comment